# combinations program help in python

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I was working on implementing a algorithm i get result at the end as
     `['0', '0', '0', '-']
     ['0', '0', '-', '0']
     ['0', '-', '0', '1']
     ['1', '0', '-', '1']
     ['1', '1', '0', '-']
     ['1', '-', '0', '1']
     ['-', '0', '0', '1']
     ['-', '1', '0', '1']
     ['-', '-', '0', '1']`

what i want is to replace the  '-' in each row and replace that with either 0 or 1  and combinations of 0 and 1  if there are two '-'s in it and give me the end in a dict() the base10 values of that row for each combination.

the number of such '-' in those strings are variable according to user input so program for n '-'s will be helpful
if not for this will help me in finding the logic.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yet so far? Where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: Really having a hard time as to determining what your desired output is

Comment: can you also give the expected output???

Comment: my output should be 1: 0,1 2:0,2 3:1,5 4:9,11 5:12,13 6:9,13 7:1,9 8:5,13 9:1,5,9,13

Comment: trying all combinations of 0's and 1's in each row having '-'

Comment: I am having hard-time understanding what is the format of your result above (in the code snippet). Is it lists within a list i.e. nested list, or something else?

Comment: So when you say base 10, you really mean 10 binary, according to your desired result.

Comment: @hagubear: It's a dictionary where the keys are numbers and the values are lists of numbers. Visual noise like braces and brackets omitted for clarity. :-)

Comment: @MOehm           It's called confusion, not clarity.

Comment: i want the row number as key in the dictionary and the combinations for the row as values each row is a binary number when joined suppose '0','0','0','1' is 0001 which is 1 when converted so for example '0','0','0','-' has two combinations '0','0','0','0' and '0','0','0','1' which are 0,1 so in dictionary key 1 should have values [0,1]

Comment: @hagubear: Well that should have been a sarcastic smirkey rather than a smiley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I've done the hard part hoping you can finish it up:

```
tmp = []                                                                        
def recal(_list):                                                                    
    n = []                                                                      
        if '-' in _list:                                                                
        for i in 0,1:                                                           
            t = _list[:]                                                            
            t[t.index('-')] = i                                                 
            n.append(recall(t))                                                   
    else:                                                                       
        tmp.append(l)                                                           
        return l                                                                

recall(['-','-','0','1'])
for l in tmp:
    print int(''.join(l),2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem descrition is hard to understand. From your comments I guess that for each list you want to find the list of binary values the digits can describe if the wildcards `'-'` are replaced with 1 or 0.

Here's how:

```
def binvalues(s):
    if '-' in s:
        return (binvalues(s.replace('-', '0', 1))
            + binvalues(s.replace('-', '1', 1)))
    else:
        return [int(s, 2)]

def bindict(q):
    d = {}        
    for i, s in enumerate(q):
        d[i + 1] = binvalues("".join(s))

    return d

print bindict([
    ['0', '0', '0', '-'],
    ['0', '0', '-', '0'],
    ['0', '-', '0', '1'],
    ['1', '0', '-', '1'],
    ['1', '1', '0', '-'],
    ['1', '-', '0', '1'],
    ['-', '0', '0', '1'],
    ['-', '1', '0', '1'],
    ['-', '-', '0', '1']
])
```

The first thing the function `bindict` does to process the list is to turn it into a string. Then you can write a recursive algorithm that replaces each `-` with 0 and 1 (one at a time, hence the second argument to `replace`, 1) and that returns a list containing a single number when there is no wildcard. The conversion function `int` takes a possible second argument, which is the base.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it wasn't for the typo.